# How to use proxy server with dokuwiki module in python

Tags: python, proxy, dokuwiki

I am trying to write an application to easy my HP disk replacement procedure for work.

We use dokuwiki for tracking cases and I would like to implement it with python so it would be done automatically when replacing a disk. Unfortunately we have to use a proxy to reach the dokuwiki link and I cannot find a way to use it whilst inside python.

So when I am trying to run the following in python IDE I always get an error even though I have set up the http/https_proxy inside venv as well.

### In [20]: wiki = dokuwiki.DokuWiki('https://172.xx.xx.xx/doku.php?id=xx:xx', 'username', 'password')

I expect no errors when running the command but I get the following:

SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 wiki = dokuwiki.DokuWiki('https://172.xx.xx.xx/doku.php?id=xx:xx', 'username', 'password')
......
......

.....

SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SSL certificates` are issued and verified against a `FQDN` (Fully Qualified Domain Name) so if you use `https` with an `IP address`, the certificate can't be verified. If you can, access you're wiki through the `FQDN` and ensure the certificate is valid.

Otherwise you can disable the [verification of the certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461969/disable-default-certificate-verification-in-python-2-7-9) (not really a good security practice). As extra parameters are directly passed to the `xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy` object, something like this should work:

```
import dokuwiki
import ssl

wiki = dokuwiki.DokuWiki('https://172.xx.xx.xx', 'username', 'password', context=ssl._create_unverified_context())
```

**Note:** The `dokuwiki` module also append the `XMLRPC URI` (`/lib/exe/xmlrpc.php`) itself so the `/doku.php?id=xx:xx` part is not necessary.